# Error 1001. An exception occurred in the OnAfterInstall event handler of a installer.cs class

Tags: .net-core, windows-installer, .net-standard-2.0, .net-4.8

Currently my Application containing both .net standard and .net framework Application , during the installation of a msi I am getting the below error.

```
 Error 1001. Error 1001. An exception occurred in the OnAfterInstall event handler of Interop.Service.Installer. --> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Diagnostics.EventLog, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

when I am tring to add the System.Diagnostics.EventLog of .net standard library into .net framework app its showing duplication error.

```
Error    CS0433    The type 'EventLogEntryType' exists in both 'System.Diagnostics.EventLog, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' and 'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'    SPI.Service    D:\Cluster01_Test\Process\Service\ServiceInstaller.cs
```

Comment: Any luck with this? I have the same error

Comment: yes that issue got fixed , i have updated this particular package in my Wix project now my application is able to load this package.